# How do I add authentication for the new Timeline feature for Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I already have a "Connect with Facebook" button. Can I add the Timeline authentication as an extended permission? Also, can I already publish using the Timeline, or do I have to wait until Timeline is available for everyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish to the timeline now even though not everyone has it. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/